# Join 3 temp tables into 1 result table by merging columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a huge query that creates a cte of warehouses and uses this to create 3 more cte's with the same column names.
below is my T-Sql query:

```
With WhList AS (SELECT Company, Warehouse FROM
CCWMS.dbo.WMSWarehouse_Control),
CoB AS (SELECT 'B' AS Company, B_IMB.Warehouse, B_IMB.StockCode, B_IMB.Bin, B_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, B_IMB.SoQtyToShip, B_IMB.LastReceiptDate,B_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyB.dbo.InvMultBin AS B_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON B_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0),
CoX AS (SELECT 'X' AS Company, X_IMB.Warehouse, X_IMB.StockCode, X_IMB.Bin, X_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, X_IMB.SoQtyToShip, X_IMB.LastReceiptDate,X_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyX.dbo.InvMultBin AS X_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON X_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0),
CoH AS (SELECT 'H' AS Company, H_IMB.Warehouse, H_IMB.StockCode, H_IMB.Bin, H_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, H_IMB.SoQtyToShip, H_IMB.LastReceiptDate,H_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyH.dbo.InvMultBin AS H_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON H_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0)
```

I need to compile these three cte's into one result set.

Any way I might be able to achieve this. I have thought about PIVOT but cant seem to wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: there are 4 CTEs, which three you wish to combine?

Comment: WhList is used to compile CoB, CoH and CoX, thus WhList does not need to be in the combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I cant believe I didn't think of this. Answer as follows:

```
--CTE's end here.
SELECT * FROM CoB
UNION
SELECT * FROM CoX
UNION
SELECT * FROM CoH
```

Thanks though

Comment: this would be my answer after your clarification

Comment: Thanks though @avb

Comment: Union will do distinct, If you really require distinct values go for 'UNION' else go for 'Union ALL'

Comment: No values will be duplicated in these tables so union all wont be needed. Invmultbin tables af the CTE's restrict duplicates making them distinct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for union all of all the results... What do you mean by combining the results?

Are you looking something like below?

```
SELECT Company, Warehouse FROM (
SELECT 'B' AS Company, B_IMB.Warehouse, B_IMB.StockCode, B_IMB.Bin, B_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, B_IMB.SoQtyToShip, B_IMB.LastReceiptDate,B_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyB.dbo.InvMultBin AS B_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON B_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'X' AS Company, X_IMB.Warehouse, X_IMB.StockCode, X_IMB.Bin, X_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, X_IMB.SoQtyToShip, X_IMB.LastReceiptDate,X_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyX.dbo.InvMultBin AS X_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON X_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'H' AS Company, H_IMB.Warehouse, H_IMB.StockCode, H_IMB.Bin, H_IMB.QtyOnHand1 AS QtyOnHand, H_IMB.SoQtyToShip, H_IMB.LastReceiptDate,H_IMB.OnHold FROM SysproCompanyH.dbo.InvMultBin AS H_IMB RIGHT JOIN WhList As WL ON H_IMB.Warehouse=WL.Warehouse WHERE QtyOnHand1 <> 0
) A
```

Comment: All Columns in the Co CTE's should be displayed but yes you have the same idea. I did answer my own question a bit too late. but will accept yours too as it comes down to the same concept. thanks though.